# Disk Utility in High Sierra 10.13.1 partitioning fail

Tags: disk-utility, partition, recovery

Before moving to Mac Sierra, main media disk was portioned in two volumes;
Main with OS space 200GB, Subsidiary with 800 GB.

I wanted to delete the subsidiary to merge it again with the Main, and then resize the Main to 400GB, and the remaining 600GB to a new volume.

It didn't work:
main stayed, the previous Sub volume of 600 disappeared completely and was in hidden modus added to the Recovery HD.

Now we have the following status:

```
iMacvanFreddy2:~ freddyvandercruyssen$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            201.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             798.8 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB    disk1
   1:                       0xEF                         4.1 MB     disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +536.9 MB   disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS StellarPartitionManager 536.9 MB   disk2s2

diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            201.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             798.8 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB    disk1
   1:                       0xEF                         4.1 MB     disk1s2
```

what commands to enter to resize the HD recovery disk, and to regain the rest of the volume in a new part

Comment: Do you want to recover the content of the now vanished "Subsidiary (800 GB)"?

Comment: the content of the removed Subsidiary is safe in an external copy.

Comment: the 800 GB are not usable,system detects them with terminal,as being part of the recovery HD; see below:

Comment: dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            201.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             798.8 GB   disk0s3

Comment: thanks a lot, we are back, super.
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical): #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER 0: GUID_partition_scheme *1.0 TB disk0 1: EFI EFI 209.7 MB disk0s1 2: Apple_HFS Macintosh HD 289.9 GB disk0s2 3: Apple_HFS Subsidiary 699.7 GB disk0s3 4: Apple_HFS Recovery HD 10.2 GB disk0s4 only 1 more final thing: the recovery HD map is visible in finder, and do i need to copy the full mac High sierra dmg in it (only 500 MB) ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the recovery partition - it's probably broken; at least it's consuming 80% of your disk. Then you have to resize your main partition disk0s2. Finally restore/rebuild the recovery partition.

1. Open Terminal.app and enter `diskutil list` to get the details
2. Check the disk: `diskutil verifyDisk disk0`.
3. `diskutil eraseVolume Free n disk0s3`
4. `diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 R` to resize the main volume to the max.

   If the R size option fails try to use a real size like 120g or the percentage 100% (on some external disks this may fail because of some 2 TiB limit).

   ```
   diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 1000g
   ```

   or a little less if this also fails

   ```
   diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 999800m
   ```
5. Recreate the recovery partition by downloading and reinstalling the latest High Sierra version (10.3.2 as of time of writing). Reinstalling won't delete your data. A Time Machine backup is recommended though.